# Python Regex getting index name and column names

Tags: python, regex

For each of the following input lines I need to get the index name and the column names.

```
PRIMARY INDEX FIRST_ONE ( PLATFORM_CD ,SYSTEM_NAME ,DB_NAME ,TABLE_NAME ,COLUMN_NAME );
) PRIMARY INDEX SECOND_ONE ( Hq_Id);
PRIMARY INDEX THIRD_ONE ( DB_NAME ,BU_NAME );
PRIMARY INDEX FOURTH_ONE ( DB_NAME ,TABLE_NAME ,COLUMN_NAME,  PII_CD);
UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX FIFT_ONE( DB_NAME,PRIMARY_SYSTEM_NAME);
```

for example for the first line of input I need to get :

```
index name : FIRST_ONE
column1 : PLATFORM_CD
column2 : SYSTEM_NAME
column3 : DB_NAME
column4 : TABLE_NAME
column5 : COLUMN_NAME
```

the regex which I have written is able to select the column names.
the regex is :

```
(?:(?<=,|\())\s*(\w+)\s*(?:\s*(\w+)\s*)?
```

what change should I make to get the index name also?
can anyone suggest a regex.
I am a beginner in regex.
the regex needs to provide output for each format of input I provided.

Comment: You could match `(?<=INDEX)[^;]+;` and split the output on `\W+`

Comment: `\w+(?=\s*\()|(?:(?<=,|\())\s*(\w+)\s*(?:\s*(\w+)\s*)?` - https://regex101.com/r/v29nQA/2

Answer (score 0):

Beside a regex you can make use of [sqlparse](https://github.com/andialbrecht/sqlparse) and split the strings:

```
import sqlparse
stmts = """PRIMARY INDEX FIRST_ONE ( PLATFORM_CD ,SYSTEM_NAME ,DB_NAME ,
TABLE_NAME ,COLUMN_NAME );
) PRIMARY INDEX SECOND_ONE ( Hq_Id);
PRIMARY INDEX THIRD_ONE ( DB_NAME ,BU_NAME );
PRIMARY INDEX FOURTH_ONE ( DB_NAME ,TABLE_NAME ,COLUMN_NAME,  PII_CD);
UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX FIFT_ONE( DB_NAME,PRIMARY_SYSTEM_NAME);"""

for stmt in sqlparse.split(stmts):
    res = sqlparse.parse(stmt)   # parses each statement
    for tok in (res[0].tokens):  # iterate all tokens
        if isinstance(tok, sqlparse.sql.Function):
            idx, columns = str(tok).split('(')
            cols = [c.strip() for c in columns[:columns.find(')')].split(',')]
            print (idx.strip(),  cols)
```

Returns:

```
FIRST_ONE ['PLATFORM_CD', 'SYSTEM_NAME', 'DB_NAME', 'TABLE_NAME', 'COLUMN_NAME']
SECOND_ONE ['Hq_Id']
THIRD_ONE ['DB_NAME', 'BU_NAME']
FOURTH_ONE ['DB_NAME', 'TABLE_NAME', 'COLUMN_NAME', 'PII_CD']
FIFT_ONE ['DB_NAME', 'PRIMARY_SYSTEM_NAME']
```

Answer (score 0):

This works assuming that you don't have any whitespaces after the commas in the table columns listing)

```
((?<=INDEX\s)[a-zA-Z_]+)|(?<=\(\s|)[a-zA-Z_]+
```

The first group will return the index name. The subsequent ones the different columns.

Explanation:

- Lookback to find INDEX plus whitespace
- Group1: Word consisting of character a-z or A-Z or _
- Or lookback to find a bracket "("
- Group2 to x: Word consisting of character a-z or A-Z or _

See example: https://regex101.com/r/AkIrcF/1

Answer (score 0):

The Regex mentioned by splash58 works ..

\w+(?=\s*()|(?:(?<=,|())\s*(\w+)\s*(?:\s*(\w+)\s*)?